# Biggest square in a grid

Tags: math, grid, graph-theory, fastest-code

### Challenge

Given a grid like this,

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 . . . . . . . .
2 . # . . . # . .
3 . . . . . . . .
4 . . . . . . . .
5 . . . . . . . .
6 . . # . . . . .
7 . . . . . . . .
8 . . . . . . . .
```

write a piece of code that can determine the size of the largest square that does not include a '#'. (The answer to this input is 5x5 as the bottom right 5x5 grid is the biggest square possible).

The square must have sides parallel to the x and y axes.

As some small details: the original grid is always a square and its side length is given to you. The coordinates of the '#' symbols are also given to you.

### Input Details

First line: N (1 <= N <= 1000), the side length of the square grid, and T (1 <= T <= 10,000) the number of '#' signs.

Next T Lines: The coordinates of each of the T #'s

### Test Cases

Input #1:

```
8 3
2 2
2 6
6 3
```

Result #1: 5

================

Input #2:

```
8 4
1 1
1 8
8 1
8 8
```

Result #2: 6

================

Input #3:

```
5 1
3 3
```

Result #3: 2

This is a [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code) problem, so the fastest code tested on the [rextester](http://rextester.com/) compiler wins.

Have fun!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79498/find-a-maximal-rectangle-of-1s).

Comment: For `fastest-code` 1000x1000 is too small, though

Comment: But rextester doesn't support Jelly or Hexagony.

Comment: @user202729 I guess you meet memory lack first

Comment: As capable as rextester is, may I recommend using [try it online](https://tio.run) instead? It contains many more langauges, and is community run.

Comment: @ATaco https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/is-tio-acceptable-for-fastest-code-questions

Comment: maybe TIO as pretest?

Comment: "the fastest code tested on the rextester compiler wins" - fastest on what input?

Comment: @user202729 rextester should have exactly the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Node.js](https://nodejs.org)

Takes input as **(w, l)**, where **w** is the width and **l** is an array of coordinates **[x, y]**. (This may be changed if the input format really is as strict as described.) Works in **O(w²)**.

```javascript
f = (w, l) => {
  var x, y,
      W = w * w,
      a = new Uint16Array(W),
      best = 0;

  l.forEach(([x, y]) => a[(y - 1) * w + x - 1] = 1);

  for(y = w; y < W; y += w) {
    for(x = y + 1; x < y + w; x++) {
      if(a[x]) {
        a[x] = 0;
      }
      else {
        best = Math.max(
          best,
          a[x] = Math.min(a[x - 1], a[x - w], a[x - w - 1]) + 1
        );
      }
    }
  }

  return best;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDBToNAFLzvV0ziZVe2rdC0IaU18eDRi4npgXBY62IxCAZogZh@O76FQjGpctidN2/em1k@1FHluyz6KiZJ@qabJsQGvJSIBTb3@GbAUWWoJGpJ2HxbUpS4RdkTiohEl3iJksJePmSZqvlW9N1XnRckuPMYEfE0TLNHtdtz7pudQeuifF5jAluYrbBQmSKgIVu0UzRDAnL1UGONrbksKkWbr@tX1CcWtkfj6xaSvLKsXgREIVd@FVwIik51F66rT@dbx7keyc5veFLFfvqpKj40upYc1eeNnTRKjGP7GokOlRfU8sJkHubF7yDmPJk/kOnikCWtmcdOzS5N8jTW0zh956FJ45oIfjvjOxJOIAe87PFSYh4QDJgQHmYzPOv8EBe4sVdYMMb@XWpL84YBuz12R7xr@GsGzgrLawaLkcH8r3TzFRzW/AA)

Comment: ```console.log(f(
  1000,
  [...Array(10000)].map(_=>[Math.random()*1000+1|0,Math.random()*1000+1|0])
)); ``` cost 114ms, though it might be the language's low efficiency

Comment: It's more like [8ms inside f()](https://tio.run/##rVHNb4IwFL/7V7xkB9uBhLJkF8RkB49LPGzxQMjSaZksWExhAtn829lr6wdb1JM90L73@3otn3zLy4XKNtVIFkvRdSlEQGoXcgrRBL4HAFuuoHGhdfGs1xwZNdxDfWhwbEhRw2smK/b4pBRvyZwe0HdRVkjwwwE2ci8t1JQvVoTE2jMxKTwmLYyAUe0KDjS6SFDEqFGhBgmYGkILY5jrzcGSmvks3iCOXWAhysfmiPTGcQ4kgCwlPG6SUwNHx9oOZ@vdfhd5KXq0/R2eebXy1rwhR8BCbq/eO1pqJnWiuY0L9lSfTqZP9cxHPf07iP7u9AsoUX0pacLCwa6b@VHseZ59aubjogkOtiFv0SQ20YrLZbEm9F6jDvvx3fPtBBNn7KZuwS3dFoUsi1x4VbYWZPii/8MdG/aAvPggqclxYebTf5KpXJ5V9e2Ci3bsil1wye7hol1wxU6rul8) after JIT compilation. (But yeah... answers are not going to be scored that way.)

Comment: I doubt the OP will add a more objective winning criteria...

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc)

No fancy algorithm here, just almost-bruteforce... but hey, C is fast.

**Input:** Takes input from *stdin*.

**Output:** Writes output to *stdout*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint_fast16_t n, t, i, j, h, x, y, flag, biggest = 0;
    scanf("%hi %hi", &n, &t);
    uint_fast8_t m[n][n];
    for (uint_fast16_t c = 0; c < t; ++c) {
        scanf("%hi %hi", &i, &j);
        m[i-1][j-1] = '#';
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; ++j) {
            flag = 1;
            for (h = 1; flag && i + h < n + 1 && j + h < n + 1; ++h) {
                for (y = i; flag && y < i + h; ++y) {
                    for (x = j; flag && x < j + h; ++x) {
                        if (m[y][x] == '#') flag = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (flag && h > biggest) biggest = h;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", biggest);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHxaoMwEMb/1qf4aJlVTMdsoRTs@iJSitNqEqodNR3K8NndJamthYFJyN33/bzLZcsyy4ZhLursfMtP2DUqF5d3vndfQ7XSMZdOVKmo/Z@LyAP8us6NQscibVS0OSrUDIpBMEgGztAydAzFOS0ZvkRZnhqFT3zErtNkaV34szcuQGvG4JHVU0E8IW4JWCX1gT4KF5cr/Ne/ZQZGxw4qRhhmpqJ/2FSQJzXbqRKxjA6JpI3Mi/mCgv0dLixOEK7GEpFGCos0eWnzcpqXNu/oHikdxeai1dxcTfPwPKKG4MYZItIBOQ1oFL@jrL0ju3ja0ZHUMLS0G6VW25JWPrUtSeUobR9SRxTwq6Q7JC31bpoPcK/7I7aa3n3uWj4iOfbjAIPJJLmxaXlvnvH7SvPRT5/PHgOnZ@@HYYu1u8KK1sbdYP0H)