# The biggest square

Tags: code-golf, matrix

This question is similar to [Biggest Square in a grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152305/biggest-square-in-a-grid).

**Challenge**

Given a matrix of `1` and `0` in a string format `"xxxx,xxxxx,xxxx,xx.."` or array format `["xxxx","xxxx","xxxx",...]`, You will create a function that determines the area of the largest square submatrix that contains all `1`.

A square submatrix is one of equal width and height, and your function should return the area of the largest submatrix that contains only `1`.

**For Example:**

Given `"10100,10111,11111,10010"`, this looks like the following matrix:

1 0 1 0 0

1 0 1 **1 1**

1 1 1 **1 1**

1 0 0 1 0

You can see the bolded `1` create the largest square submatrix of size 2x2, so your program should return the area which is 4.

**Rules**

- Submatrix must be one of equal width and height
- Submatrix must contains only values `1`
- Your function must return the area of the largest submatrix
- In case no submatrix is found, return `1`
- You can calculate the area of the submatrix by counting the number of `1` in the submatrix

**Test cases**

**Input:** `"10100,10111,11111,10010"` **Output:** `4`

**Input:** `"0111,1111,1111,1111"` **Output:** `9`

**Input** `"0111,1101,0111"` **Output:** `1`

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes win.

Comment: Why string format?

Comment: Done, Thanks for your suggestions @StewieGriffin

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of the question you linked to? The only thing different is the IO format and the delimiters.

Comment: Can we take the input as a binary (numeric) matrix?

Comment: This looks very similar to the (now deleted) challenge [Squares, so many squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/144923/73111).

Comment: @Nit Not exactly. First the other one is a closed, out of topic question. also is not `code-golf`, it is `fastest-code`. That's why i came with this one. Hope it is no problem with it

Comment: @StewieGriffin No sorry. Just array or string input

Comment: @JonathanFrech Sorry, never saw that question. Hope there is no problem

Comment: Is `["xxxx";"xxxx";"xxxx";...]` ok a input?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes

Comment: For [0] still required to output 1?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes. Remember, `In case no submatrix is found, return 1`

Comment: Hang about, why return 1 when no all-1 sub-matrix is found, wouldn't 0 make much more sense? (Otherwise it is simply a special case to handle)

Comment: As it stands I think both answerers would not mind if you changed the specs and I strongly recommend doing so because there's no point for returning 1 and it doesn't make the submissions more interesting.

Comment: This question appears to be taken from [here](https://coderbyte.com/editor/guest:Maximal%20Square:Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sub>+2 to handle no-all-1 sublist present output</sub>

```
ẆZṡ¥"L€$ẎȦÐfL€Ṁ²»1
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrraohzsXHlqq5POoaY3Kw119J5YdnpAG4jzc2XBo0////6OjDXUMdEDYIFYHygZCMNsQiW0AURUbCwA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrraohzsXHlqq5POoaY3Kw119J5YdnpAG4jzc2XBo06Hdhv8PtwN5//9HR0cb6hjogLBBrA6UDYRgtiES2wCiKjZWh0shOhpDFVYWNrUGYBZMLDYWAA)

#### How?

```
ẆZṡ¥"L€$ẎȦÐfL€Ṁ²»1 - Link: list of lists of 1s and 0s
Ẇ                  - all slices (lists of "rows") call these S = [s1,s2,...]
       $           - last two links as a monad:
     L€            -   length of each (number of rows in each slice) call these X = [x1, x2, ...]
    "              -   zip with (i.e. [f(s1,x1),f(s2,x2),...]):
   ¥               -     last two links as a dyad:
 Z                 -       transpose (get the columns of the current slice)
  ṡ                -       all slices of length xi (i.e. squares of he slice)
        Ẏ          - tighten (to get a list of the square sub-matrices)
          Ðf       - filter keep if:
         Ȧ         -   any & all (all non-zero when flattened?)
            L€     - length of €ach (the side length)
              Ṁ    - maximum
               ²   - square (the maximal area)
                »1 - maximum of that and 1 (to coerce a 0 found area to 1)
```

Comment: Awesome. Can you add some explanation?

Comment: I will, I'm trying to think of shorter first...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I have updated to handle the requirement for now

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>113 121 118</s> 117 bytes

```hs
x!s=[0..length x-s]
t#d=take t.drop d
f x=last$1:[s*s|s<-min(x!0)$x!!0!0,i<-x!!0!s,j<-x!s,all(>'0')$s#i=<<(s#j)x,s>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbBCoMgGADgu0/xS0I1TPQ6tBeJDrJsWWajX5iHvbtbO3zwLRY3F0IpmaIZpBDBxWdaIHc4klRNJtnNQRLTebxgIjNkEywmpu4D3vCDutt9bDKVLcuUSiq5191/yNdryG0ITV/LumVYeaN1g9XaZo69HMtufQQDPiZ32kcCBrgcbxAw/wQfHRaplCJKSUWufQE)

<sub>-3 bytes thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni?tab=profile)!</sub>

<sub>-1 byte thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn?tab=profile)!</sub>

<sub>+8 bytes for the ridiculous requirement of returning 1 for no all-1s sub-matrix..</sub>

#### Explanation/Ungolfed

The following helper function just creates offsets for `x` allowing to decrement them by `s`:

```hs
x!s=[0..length x-s]
```

`x#y` will drop `y` elements from a list and then take `x`:

```hs
t#d=take t.drop d
```

The function `f` loops over all possible sizes for sub-matrices in order, generates each sub-matrix of the corresponding size, tests whether it contains only `'1'`s and stores the size. Thus the solution will be the last entry in the list:

```hs
--          v prepend a 1 for no all-1s submatrices
f x= last $ 1 : [ s*s
                -- all possible sizes are given by the minimum side-length
                | s <- min(x!0)$x!!0!0
                -- the horizontal offsets are [0..length(x!!0) - s]
                , i <- x!!0!s
                -- the vertical offsets are [0..length x - s]
                , j <- x!s
                -- test whether all are '1's
                , all(>'0') $
                -- from each row: drop first i elements and take s (concatenates them to a single string)
                              s#i =<<
                -- drop the first j rows and take s from the remaining
                                      (s#j) x
                -- exclude size 0...........................................
                , s>0
                ]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```apl
{⌈/{×⍨⍵×1∊{∧/∊⍵}⌺⍵ ⍵⊢X}¨⍳⌊/⍴X←⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRT4d@9eHpj3pXPOrdeni64aOOrupHHcv1gTRQoPZRzy4gpQDEj7oWRdQeAqra/KinS/9R75aIR20TQEr@/3cDsqhgENejvqlAJtC0iRqGCgYKIGygCWUCIYhpiGAaQJRoAgA)

[Adám's SBCS has all of the characters in the code](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

Explanation coming eventually!

Comment: You had me at 'explanation', lol.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>99</s> 97 bytes

```hs
b s@((_:_):_)=maximum$sum[length s^2|s==('1'<$s<$s)]:map b[init s,tail s,init<$>s,tail<$>s]
b _=1
```

Checks if input is a square matrix of just ones with `s==('1'<$s<$s)`, if it is, answer is length^2, else 0. Then recursively chops first/last column/row and takes the maximum value it finds anywhere.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtNCoMwEIX3nmIoghFEki7FlF6gJxAbEio11KTiRNpF754mpliYv/e9N6PExzBN3ivAMyGiEWUobuRbm9XkuJpuGuzdjYDX4wc5JwUr2hxDlX1j5Ayq01Y7wMpJPYUVVZufko5HnykQnHkjtQUO4ecigMyLtq5W9eu53LDMAKA7MMZgb0oPkVaJ0o3@yN@BnQWX0ZjZkjT9hBlHyvT@Cw)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>33</strike> 27 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog!

```
[:>./@,,~@#\(#**/)@,;._3"$]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D/ayk5P30FHp85BOUZDWUtLX9NBx1ov3lhJJfa/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQq2VQloxF1dqcka@QpqCsYKpiiHQCBCGkIYYECoD02KiYKKCTRkSRJiOqhTJhv8A)

### Explanation:

I'll use the first test case in my explanation:

```
    ] a =. 3 5$1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

I generate all the possible square submatrices with size from 1 to the number of rows of the input.

`,~@#\` creates a list of pairs for the sizes of the submatrices by stitching `,.` togehter the length of the successive prefixes `#\` of the input:

```
   ,~@#\ a
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Then I use them to cut `x u ;. _3 y` the input into submatrices. I already have `x` (the list of sizes); `y` is the right argument `]` (the input).

```
 ((,~@#\)<;._3"$]) a
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───┬─┐
│1    │0    │1    │0  │0│
│     │     │     │   │ │
│     │     │     │   │ │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼───┼─┤
│1    │0    │1    │1  │1│
│     │     │     │   │ │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼───┼─┤
│1    │1    │1    │1  │1│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───┴─┘

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───┬─┐
│1 0  │0 1  │1 0  │0 0│ │
│1 0  │0 1  │1 1  │1 1│ │
│     │     │     │   │ │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼───┼─┤
│1 0  │0 1  │1 1  │1 1│ │
│1 1  │1 1  │1 1  │1 1│ │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼───┼─┤
│     │     │     │   │ │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───┴─┘

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───┬─┐
│1 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│   │ │
│1 0 1│0 1 1│1 1 1│   │ │
│1 1 1│1 1 1│1 1 1│   │ │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼───┼─┤
│     │     │     │   │ │
│     │     │     │   │ │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼───┼─┤
│     │     │     │   │ │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───┴─┘
```

For each submatrix I check if it consist entirely of 1s:
`(#**/)@,` - flatten the matrix, and mutiply the number of items by their product. If all items are 1s, the result will be their sum, otherwise - 0:

```
   (#**/)@, 3 3$1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0
   (#**/)@, 2 2$1 1 1 1
4 

   ((,~@#\)(+/**/)@,;._3"$]) a
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1

0 0 0 0 0
0 0 4 4 0
0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Finally I flatten the list of results for each submatrix and find the maximum:

`>./@,`

```
   ([:>./@,,~@#\(+/**/)@,;._3"$]) a
4
```

Comment: ``,~@#\`` and ``"1 2`` -> ``"$``

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thank you! I didn't know about `"$`

Comment: `#` is shorter than adding up the 1s.

Comment: @ FrownyFrog Hmm, it really is. Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), <s>33</s> 28 bytes

```
{*/2#+/|/',/'{0&':'0&':x}\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpL30hZW79GX11HX73aQE3dSh1EVNTGVNT@L7GqVomurCuySlOosE7Iz7bWSEhLzMyxrrCutC7SjK3lKonWMFQwUABhA2sICwitDRUM4SwDiLymtUksSDmaEnRa09oSQxmQbW0AkzaM/Q8A)

Comment: I never knew you had a K version!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 63 bytes

```ruby
p (1..l=$_=~/,|$/).map{|i|/#{[?1*i]*i*(?.*(l-i+1))}/?i*i:1}.max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBw1BPL8dWJd62Tl@nRkVfUy83saC6JrNGX7k62t5QKzNWK1NLw15PSyNHN1PbUFOzVt8@UyvTyrAWqLDi/39DA0MDAx0gaWioY2gIJg2AQlxwAQQBEzMw1DEAc//lF5Rk5ucV/9fNAwA)

Ruby version of my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163441/78274). Golfier as a full program. Alternatively, an anonymous lambda:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```ruby
->s{(1..l=s=~/,|$/).map{|i|s=~/#{[?1*i]*i*(?.*(l-i+1))}/?i*i:1}.max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664WsNQTy/Htti2Tl@nRkVfUy83saC6JrMGJKBcHW1vqJUZq5WppWGvp6WRo5upbaipWatvn6mVaWVYC1RbUfu/QCEtWsnQwNDAQAdIGhrqGBqCSQOgkFIsF1gaLo4g0KQMDHUMkEWVYv8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 143 bytes

```
%`$
,;#
+%(`(\d\d.+;#)#*
$1¶$&¶$&#
\G\d(\d+,)|\G((;#+¶|,)\d)\d+
$1$2
)r`((11)|\d\d)(\d*,;?#*)\G
$#2$3
1,
#
Lv$`(#+).*;\1
$.($.1*$1
N`
-1G`
^$
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw9DsIwDIV3X8Mucn6o8sqYgTEL4gQRClIZWBgqxNRz9QC9WEiRAMl@evr8ydPteX9cUTtNpXZFyEcm12nRPOaxd5ENWxKsi@y2Zcopj@3ovJlzUo3s1mX2Jo9tXDNlIDMVVaAJ7YdpsvXxyNbkRMKDHAiemE4vKcrO9DZmkPQqPayAzoX2SIUuQqgVASH4loAHPhkaoh/4x5cF@K29AQ) Link includes test cases. Takes input as comma-separated strings. Explanation:

```
%`$
,;#
```

Add a `,` to terminate the last string, a `;` to separate the strings from the `#`s and a `#` as a counter.

```
+%(`
)
```

Repeat the block until no more subsitutions happen (because each string is now only one digit long).

```
(\d\d.+;#)#*
$1¶$&¶$&#
```

Triplicate the line, setting the counter to 1 on the first line and incrementing it on the last line.

```
\G\d(\d+,)|\G((;#+¶|,)\d)\d+
$1$2
```

On the first line, delete the first digit of each string, while on the second line, delete all the digits but the first.

```
r`((11)|\d\d)(\d*,;?#*)\G
$#2$3
```

On the third line, bitwise and the first two digits together.

```
1,
#
```

At this point, each line consists of two values, a) a horizontal width counter and b) the bitwise and of that many bits taken from each string. Convert any remaining `1`s to `#`s so that they can be compared against the counter.

```
Lv$`(#+).*;\1
$.($.1*$1
```

Find any runs of bits (vertically) that match the counter (horizontally), corresponding to squares of `1`s in the original input, and square the length.

```
N`
```

Sort numerically.

```
-1G`
```

Take the largest.

```
^$
1
```

Special-case the zero matrix.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 92 bytes

```
a=>(g=w=>a.match(Array(w).fill(`1{${w}}`).join(`..{${W-w}}`))?w*w:g(w-1))(W=a.indexOf`,`)||1
```

```js
f=
a=>(g=w=>a.match(Array(w).fill(`1{${w}}`).join(`..{${W-w}}`))?w*w:g(w-1))(W=a.indexOf`,`)||1
console.log(f('0111,1111,1111,1111'));
console.log(f('10100,10111,11111,10010'));
console.log(f('0111,1101,0111'));
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```apl
×⍨{1∊⍵:1+∇2×/2×⌿⍵⋄0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/04Dk4emPeldUGz7q6HrUu9XKUPtRR7vR4en6QPyoZz9Q6FF3i0Ht//8lQKXVIG7nwiIgM@1R7y4r9fxsdaC0elpiZo46UAAoXVTLpfGot@/QikdtE9UNDQwNDNQVQLShIYg2hNIGQAl1zRIFEyTFSGrQKKBCS2wKDUCUAVSFIQA)

Comment: Recursion! Nice!

Comment: @Zacharý Thanks. Actually, instead of recursion I'd prefer something like k's f\x for a monadic f, which is  (x; f x; f f x; ...) until convergence, but there's no equivalent in APL (yet). Doing it with ⍣≡ takes too many bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>117</s> 109 bytes

Credit to @etene for pointing out an inefficiency that cost me an additional byte.

```python
lambda s:max(i*i for i in range(len(s))if re.search(("."*(s.find(',')-i+1)).join(["1"*i]*i),s))or 1
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDgIhEET7@wpCc7uIhLU08UvUAj3w1nhwgSv065FYnImxecW8mZlfy5jirobDqT7cdBmcKPvJPYEVi5CyYMFRZBdvHh4@QkHkILI3xbt8HQGkkQqKCRwH6HWPW94QorknjnCUJBWfFaNuu3ZGHU9zyks7qHPmuIgAkixZqxuJNNGHtkUSu7Wyui/@aEva/hqJ9Q0)

Takes input as a comma-separated string. This is a regex-based approach that tries matching the input string against patterns of the form `111.....111.....111` for all possible sizes of the square.

In my calculations, doing this with an anonymous lambda is just a tad shorter than defined function or a full program. The `or 1` part in the end is only necessary to handle the strange edge case, where we must output `1` if there are no ones in the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>116</strike> <strike>115</strike> <strike>117</strike> 109 bytes

*Credits to @Kirill for helping me golf it even more and for his clever & early solution*

*Edit*: Golfed 1 byte by using a lambda, I didn't know assigning it to a variable didn't count towards the byte count.

*Edit 2*: Kirill pointed out my solution didn't work for cases where the input only contains `1`s, I had to fix it and lost two precious bytes...

*Edit 3*: more golfing thanks to Kirill

Takes a comma separated string, returns an integer.

```python
lambda g:max(i*i for i in range(len(g))if re.search(("."*(g.find(",")+1-i)).join(["1"*i]*i),g))or 1
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBDoIwDIbvPEXTU4eTrB5JfBL1MIVBDWxkctCnn8Mg2uT/k35pv@k198Efkjue02DHa2Ohq0f7JCkFXIggIB6i9V1LQ@upU0ocxLZ6tDbeeiKssKSucuIbQo1qx3tRqroH8XRCxlIupSid/7KMCxmnEOcsSJsc2bAxOjezZv60yQg14MZ@9YcNa/Ml2bBmWdfjJVgXkGeK4mcQDY5EpTc)

I independently found an answer that is close to Kiril's one, i.e regex based, except that I use `re.search` <strike>and a `def`</strike>.

It uses a regex built during each loop to match an incrementally larger square and returns the largest one, or 1.

Comment: Nice, I somehow automatically discarded the `if` approach as "too long for sure", but then had to make up some other way to make a bool value out of the match. Unfortunately, your solution misses one point - you cannot have just `range(l)` - it will miss the case when there are no zeroes at all. E.g., take 2nd test case and make it all 1s - it should become 16, not 9.

Comment: Damn, I thought about testing with all zeroes but not with all ones (never mentioned in the challenge...). I'll try to make something up.

Comment: @KirillL. by the way, you're fast ! I was still working on my answer when you posted yours and was a bit bummed (and proud!) when I saw our approaches were similar... the level around here is impressive.

Comment: Golfed a few more bytes by getting rid of duplicated `find`. Now that our codes are not identical anymore, I suggest we at least fix the obvious mistakes from each other - in your case the extra byte comes from using tuple `("1"*i,)` instead of list.

Comment: Thank you, yeah the useless tuple is pretty stupid on my part. And the extra `find` too, that was clever of you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>138</s> 128 bytes

```python
def f(m):j=''.join;L=j(m);k=map(j,zip(*m));return len(L)and max(len(L)*(len(m)**2*'1'==L),f(k[1:]),f(k[:-1]),f(m[1:]),f(m[:-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BDoIwEEX3noLddBo0HZaQ3oAbEBYklEhxSkMwUS9fC9VojKv35/2/GH9fz7MrQujNkA2CsbQa4GTn0VW1tlFUk@bOC5s/Ri8kI1aLWa@Lyy7GiRo712fc3US65E5GKQsJBFrXmA9iaqhsUyiPtCd@K04Kg19Gt8YXGiBFSkG@kWgjvahiAS0ePtOvxQ/@z9QGlfrwBA)

---

Saved

- -10 bytes thanks to ovs

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```perl6
{(^$_ X.. ^$_).max({[~&](.[|$^r||*])~~/$(1 x$r)/&&+$r})²}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiNOJV4hQk9PAUhr6uUmVmhUR9epxWroRdeoxBXV1GjFatbV6atoGCpUqBRp6qupaasU1Woe2lT7vzixUiFNQ6@4ICezRENdR11TUyEtv4hLydDA0MBAB0gaGuoYGoJJA6CQkg6XElwMQSAJGxjqgFhK1v8B)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 193 bytes

```
#(apply max(for [f[(fn[a b](take-while seq(iterate a b)))]R(f next %)R(f butlast R)n[(count R)]c(for[i(range(-(count(first R))n -1)):when(apply = 1(for[r R c(subvec r i(+ i n))]c))](* n n))]c))
```

Wow, things escalated :o

Less golfed:

```
(def f #(for [rows (->> %    (iterate next)    (take-while seq)) ; row-postfixes
              rows (->> rows (iterate butlast) (take-while seq)) ; row-suffixes
              n    [(count rows)]
              c    (for[i(range(-(count(first rows))n -1)):when(every? pos?(for [row rows col(subvec row i(+ i n))]col))](* n n))] ; rectangular subsections
          c))
```