# Largest rectangle in a skyline

Tags: code-golf, array

A skyline is an array of positive integers where each integer represents how tall a building is. For example, if we had the array `[1,3,4,2,5,3,3]` this would be the skyline in ascii art:

```
    #
  # #
 ## ###
 ######
#######
```

Your task is to find the area of the largest rectangle in the skyline. In this case, the largest rectangle has area 12. Here is the rectangle, highlighted:

```
    #
  # #
 ## ###
 RRRRRR
#RRRRRR
```

You can assume that the input contains at least one building (the length of the array is >0). This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), you know the drill.

Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114797/minimum-rectangle-inside-of-city-skyline/114851) Puzzling-SE post.

## Test cases

```
[1] -> 1
[2, 2] -> 4
[3, 2, 1] -> 4
[1, 2, 3] -> 4
[1, 5, 1, 5] -> 5
[1, 4, 1, 4, 1] -> 5
[1, 4, 5, 4, 1] -> 12
[1, 5, 4, 5, 1] -> 12
[1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3] -> 6
[1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2] -> 8
[1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> 7
```

Comment: can we take a boolean matrix as input?

Comment: @Razetime no, it would be a different challenge and regardless almost a dupe of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79498/find-a-maximal-rectangle-of-1s)

Answer (score 9):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 50 bytes

```matlab
@(a)max(([c,v]=runlength([(a<=a').*a;0*a](:))).*v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdBCoAgEADAr3RrVxaprEsl9A/xsIjWoQzCpN@bp2Fulzj7EhotpSwbMF78ARhH2ernjaePezrAAK@aW5SCl06whRmxJmMJYHpSNNJAU1VZLD8)

Based on my PARI/GP answer, but more interesting. This worth writing a Jonah-style explanation.

#### how

Takes `a = [1,3,4,2,5,3,3]` as an example.

- `a<=a'` creates a matrix where the entry at `(i,j)` is `a[j]<=a[i]`:

  ```matlab
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
  ```
- `.*a` multiplies the `i`-th column of the matrix with `a[i]`:

  ```matlab
  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
  1   3   0   2   0   3   3
  1   3   4   2   0   3   3
  1   0   0   2   0   0   0
  1   3   4   2   5   3   3
  1   3   0   2   0   3   3
  1   3   0   2   0   3   3
  ```
- `[...;0*a]` appends a row of zeros to the matrix, so that the columns are separated when taking run length encoding:

  ```matlab
  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
  1   3   0   2   0   3   3
  1   3   4   2   0   3   3
  1   0   0   2   0   0   0
  1   3   4   2   5   3   3
  1   3   0   2   0   3   3
  1   3   0   2   0   3   3
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  ```
- `...(:)` concatenates the matrix into a column vector (the actual output is the transpose of the following row vector):

  ```matlab
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   3   3   0   3   3   3   0   0   0   4   0   4   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   3   3   0   3   3   3   0   0   3   3   0   3   3   3   0
  ```
- `[c,v]=runlength` gives the run length encoding, where each non-zero run corresponds to a rectangle in the skyline:

  ```matlab
  c =
  7   2   2   1   3   3   1   1   1   4   6   5   1   4   2   1   3   2   2   1   3   1

  v =
  1   0   3   0   3   0   4   0   4   0   2   0   5   0   3   0   3   0   3   0   3   0
  ```
- `([c,v]=runlength(...)).*v` multiplies `c` and `v` element by element, which gives the "area" of each run:

  ```matlab
  7    0    6    0    9    0    4    0    4    0   12    0    5    0    6    0    9    0    6    0    9    0
  ```
- Finally, `max` finds the maximum values of the result:

  ```matlab
  12
  ```

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ẆṂ×LƊ€Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrraHO5sOT/c51vWoac3DnQ3/D7drRv7/H20YqxNtpKNgBKSMgZSOAkjAEMwyhrBMgWJAEsIxAXNM4MpMwPIIvilMCMkYmBFQ84zBCK7XCE0UimIB)

```
Ẇ   Ɗ€     For each contiguous sublist of the input,
 Ṃ×        multiply its smallest element by
   L       its length.
      Ṁ    Return the largest product.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes basically by AnttiP

```python
f=lambda x:x>[]and max(min(x)*len(x),f(x[1:]),f(x[:-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocKqwi46NjEvRSE3sUIjNzNPo0JTKycVROmkaVREG1rFQhhWuoaxmpr/C4oy80o00jSiDXUUTHUUTMAkWAYA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
lambda x:max(min(x[i:j])*(j-i)for j in range(len(x)+1)for i in range(j))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rck9DoAgDEDhq3Rs/RmIuph4EnXACFoi1RAHPD0SF5c3fO967v2UJtlhSof2y6oh9l5H9CwYR@7dTAW6msmeARywQNCyGTxM/lSqz/l3R5SuwHKjxVFV0FXQflVzPi8)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>86</s> 85 bytes

```python
lambda x:(R:=range(0,len(x)+1))and max(min(x[i:j])*(j-i)for i in R for j in R if i<j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBCsIwEEDRq8xypkZoUEGCvUS3tYuRNjqhmYbQRTx9rLr5PH56b69VT9eUq@/udeH4mBiKw951mfU5Y2uWWbHQwRKxThC5YJT9DOLCSA2Go5BfMwiIQg9fhj/Fg9wC1ZRFN/Q4WAMXA@df7UhUPw)

Avoid [something](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2OlMhLb9IIVMhM08jycq2KDEvPVXDUFMz9v9/AA) by pxeger

Comment: I was going to say you could use the walrus operator in 3.8, but perhaps not...

Comment: @UnrelatedString [Something would go wrong](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2OlMhLb9IIVMhM08jycq2KDEvPVXDUFMz9v9/AA)

Comment: 59 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoUJHq8Sqwi46NjEvRSE3sUIjNzNPo0JTKycVROmkaWiV6FREG1rFAkkrXcNYTc3/BUWZeSUaaRrRhjoKpjoKJmASLAMA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: -1 on the last one: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBCsIwEEDRq8xypkZoUEGCvUS3tYuRNjqhmYbQRTx9rLr5PH56b69VT9eUq@/udeH4mBiKw951mfU5Y2uWWbHQwRKxThC5YJT9DOLCSA2Go5BfMwiIQg9fhj/Fg9wC1ZRFN/Q4WAMXA@df7UhUPw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to @att.

```
Max[Tr[Min@#+0#]&/@Subsequences@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@983sSI6pCjaNzPPQVnbQDlWTd8huDSpOLWwNDUvObXYASjyP6AoM68kWllB104hLVo5NlZBTUHfQaG62rBWR6HaSEfBCEQbA2kdBbCQIZhpDGWaAkWBJJRnAuaZIFSagFUgCZjCxJDNghkDM9QYjODajdCFoai29j8A)

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@983sSI6pCjaNzPPQVnbQDlWTd8huDSpOLWwNDUvObXYASjyP6AoM68kWllB104hLVo5NlZBTUHfQaG62rBWR6HaSEfBCEQbA2kdBbCQIZhpDGWaAkWBJJRnAuaZIFSagFUgCZjCxJDNghkDM9QYjODajdCFoai29j8A)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŒεWsg*}à
```

Port of [*@UnrelatedString*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242802/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KRzW8OL07VqDy/4/z/aUMdYx0THSMcUSBvHAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o5PObQ0vTteqPbzgv87/6GjDWB2FaCMdIxBlrGOkA@YbAhnGEIapDhBDmCY6YAzjmCI4pmAuQitYF9QAYyCEKDdCFgBDmIAJUJMpSCI2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ       # Get all sublists of the (implicit) input-list
 ε      # Map each sublist to:
  W     #  Push its minimum (without popping the sublist)
   s    #  Swap so the sublist is at the top again
    g   #  Pop and push its length
     *  #  Multiply it by the minimum
 }à     # After the map: pop and push the maximum
        # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 18 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{⌈´(+´≠⥊⌊´)¨∾↓¨↑}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge+KMiMK0KCvCtOKJoOKliuKMisK0KcKo4oi+4oaTwqjihpHwnZWpfQoKPuKLiOKfnEbiiJjigKJKc8KoIOKfqAoiWzFdIgoiWzIsIDJdIgoiWzMsIDIsIDFdIgoiWzEsIDIsIDNdIgoiWzEsIDUsIDEsIDVdIgoiWzEsIDQsIDEsIDQsIDFdIgoiWzEsIDQsIDUsIDQsIDFdIgoiWzEsIDUsIDQsIDUsIDFdIgoiWzEsIDIsIDMsIDUsIDEsIDNdIgoiWzEsIDMsIDMsIDEsIDQsIDUsIDJdIgoiWzEsIDMsIDMsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDFdIgrin6k=)

`↑` Prefixes of the input (includes the empty prefix)
`↓¨` Suffixes of each prefix
`∾` Flatten into a list of sublists
`(     )¨` For each sublist:
`≠⥊⌊´` Reshape the minimum to the length of the sublist

`+´` Sum the resulting list
`⌈´` Get the maximum result

Instead of `+´≠⥊⌊´` other answers use `≠×⌊´`, but that results in `0×∞ = NaN` for empty sublists, which ends up as the result of `⌈´`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ÞSƛgnL*;G
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnlPGm2duTCo7RyIsIiIsIlsxLCAzLCAzLCAxLCA0LCA1LCAyXSJd)

Port of Unrelated String's Jelly answer.

```
ÞSƛ    ;  # For each contiguous sublist
   g  *   # Multiply the smallest element
    nL    # The length.
        G # Get the largest product.
```

Comment: [-2 with a flag.](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJHIiwiIiwiw55TxptnbkwqIiwiIiwiWzEsIDMsIDMsIDEsIDQsIDUsIDJdIl0=)

Comment: @lyxal I know..

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 63 bytes

```r
function(l,r=rle(c(t(cbind(outer(l,l,`<=`)*l,0)))))max(r$l*r$v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/fCsIgFIfvewqhXegwyH/VRfYsK5swMAfiorc3Na2tyUHw@zy/oy5oGfRklR9GCw120pkeKuihug32DsfJ9y5yg7uz7FBr8B6l9bi@oGtM65onCjo2EIS2YHcBZJNOFANaAM@ARYABWTCSGftnIt6Le8GiYp4x/4XMjVgYQmdZH7tWaXQdVt9wqJLl@mbXv5xWvlTxx/AG)

Port of [alephalpha's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242812/55372).

Comment: I managed to get to [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY/LCsIwEEX3fsWImxltFulL0eqyPyEupBhI6AOrQkH89pjGRFsLQyDnTO5MWi0gY1o86uIumxpLeoqmRQmyhi5jt8sV5yVRz5RllO@rc4d5gJKpFadlJc2ro9yqE9Euf2mBBXKiBbAD8Fl/CwMIHYgtiAwIgI8Ytyz6Z4npM6fDicexxfEvZGiSkeHhIOtjp6of7Yf5HVIvI1vfbP@XzcS7cn6t3w) porting the "try each subsequence" strategy, but perhaps there's still a big golf I'm missing?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see one, @Giuseppe. I also got around 70-something with taking `rle` along each row to omit zero-padding like in Sundar's MATL answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
sᶠ⟨⌋×l⟩ᵐ⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv/jhtgWP5q941NN9eHrOo/krgWKPejr//4@ONozViTbSUTACUsZASkcBJGAIZhlDWKZAMSAJ4ZiAOSZwZSZgeQTfFCaEZAzMCKh5xmAE12uEJgpFsbEA)

```
sᶠ    ᵐ     For each contiguous sublist of the input,
  ⟨⌋× ⟩      multiply its smallest element by
    l       its length.
       ⌉    Return the largest product.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
&<~G!*"@Y'*vX>
```

[Try it out](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%26%3C%7EG%21%2a%22%40Y%27%2avX%3E&inputs=%5B1%3B+2%3B+3%3B+5%3B+1%3B+3%5D&version=22.4.0) or [Test all cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmfkKkQ4aEQ5adgr6CnEKvg8V/Nps5DUUvJIVJdqyzC7n9shItCVIVCSOz/aMNYrmgjawUjIGUMpKwVQAKGYJYxhGUKFAOSEI4JmGMCV2YClkfwTWFCSMbAjICaZwxGcL1GaKJQFMtloG/ABQA)

*(Edit: turns out alephalpha's idea is very similar, this just uses a loop instead of zero padding + linearization)*

With input [1; 2; 3; 5; 1; 3]

```
&<~         % make a boolean matrix, each column denoting 
            %   which buildings are >= current one
```

1 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1

```
G!*         % multiply by input
```

1 0 0 0 1 0
1 2 0 0 1 0
1 2 3 0 1 3
1 2 3 5 1 3
1 0 0 0 1 0
1 2 3 0 1 3

```
"@Y'        % for each column, take its run-length encoding
```

eg. for second column,
[0 2 0 2]
[1 3 1 1]

```
*           % multiply to get rectangle areas

vX>         % cumulatively, keep finding the maximum area

            % implicit loop end, implicit output
```

-1 byte thanks to @LuisMendo.

Comment: @LuisMendo I've probably done this every time there's a `X>` near the end, and you've helpful pointed it out every time. I never seem to learn though. :D

Comment: Haha, I didn't remember that. So, you may want to bookmark [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79863/36398)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 58 bytes

```
[ all-subseqs [ dup infimum swap length * ] map supremum ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/NCsIwEITveYo5Cxba2os@gHjxIp5KD7GmWmxjzA8qpc8etz/SohkWZr4lC1Pw3N61Px52@@0aRjyckLkwgXhZzQ1uQktRTRw1t1coLax9K11Kiw1jDQO9BiHa0UWkr4/JT5uQUjxLST9TXo0zJ8kPSXr2e7Mj88sxafgd/dFBLWt9Cl5VS@NOVNEgxdkplLIoa1fDPLlCJeSFKi@QUXcF46h8t8x8FwP/AQ)

Port of @UnrelatedString's [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242802/97916).

- `all-subseqs` Get every possible grouping of contiguous skyscrapers.
- `[ dup infimum swap length * ] map` Get the area of each grouping by multiplying the height of the shortest skyscraper in the grouping by the number of skyscrapers in the grouping.
- `supremum` Return the largest area.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 50 bytes

```
a->m=vecmax;m([m([c=(t>=s)*c+=s|t<-a*!c=0])|s<-a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7RCsIwDPyVuKd2tuDa@qTdj4w@hOJkYKWsQxT27zUrm6JwJHfHXUjEcZDXmHuwGWUb7OPiAz5PgXUEb9nU2sRrv7dpns4S6523B8fnRNzxjDHeXgxBthDH4T4RrRZRQc@QcwFd1ziaSoBatqYtoFhNoXqlR3JprsoUZb5JUxLmt7q1thu64JNW//YKR3@/AQ)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 50 bytes

```
a->m=0;[[m=max(m,c=(t>=s)*c+=s)|t<-a*!c=0]|s<-a];m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUxBCsMgEPzKNidNFRK1p9R8RDwsgZRALZLk0EL@bjdiWloYZmeGmY04T/IW0wg2oeyDbTrngg34ZEEMlq29XXg9nIm39SqxPg228dtC0nchYYz3F0OQPcR5eqwkq91UMDLkXIBzrSdWAtR@NV0BOWqz1EVeKCUuzmRnvk2TG@Z3eqyOHzrj01b/cYH3PL0B)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>+a||Math.max(Math.min(...a)*a.length,f(a.slice(1),a.pop()),f(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc9BDoIwEAXQvafostVa0gLqBm/gCUwXEyyIQUqEGBfcvQJFjVgJk8mkaV4mfy5whyq@ZWW9LvRJGZNEEO1X0DQHqM/sCg9sH1mBGWNAlsByVaT1mSYYWJVnscKcUGClLjEh3S8hJtZFpXPFcp3iBB@5RD9FCPI8xBcjKigS0kmDMfVbStH37j@U99SfScN2azvliIYOGvQ0@MSYpKGDcuFOYPkM2x32ytxfaO3GQf2@31mEtHQ3RYce6NY8AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
f =                // f is a recursive function taking:
a =>               //   a[] = skyline array
  +a ||            // if a[] is a singleton, return its unique value
  Math.max(        // otherwise, return the maximum of:
    Math.min(...a) //   1) the smallest value of a[]
    * a.length,    //      multiplied by the length of a[]
    f(             //   2) the result of a recursive call
      a.slice(1),  //      with the 1st item removed
      a.pop()      //      (remove the last item for the next call)
    ),             //   
    f(a)           //   3) the result of a recursive call
                   //      with the last item removed
  )                // end of Math.max()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｉ⌈Ｅθ⌈Ｅ⊕κ×⁻⊕κλ⌊✂θλ⊕κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexIjO3NBdIF2gU6iggcz3zkotSc1PzSlJTNLI1dRRCMnNTizV8M/NKizHkcoAYKAPWG5yTmZwKMixHRwFVHRxY//8fHW2oo2AMRkCGiY6CqY6CUWzsf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @l4m2's Python answer.

```
   θ                Input array
  Ｅ                 Map over elements
       κ            Current index
      ⊕             Incremented
     Ｅ              Map over implicit range
           κ        Outer index
          ⊕         Incremented
         ⁻          Subtract
            λ       Inner index
        ×           Multiplied by
               θ    Input array
              ✂     Sliced from
                λ   Inner index to
                  κ Outer index
                 ⊕  Incremented
             ⌊      Take the minimum
    ⌈               Take the maximum
 ⌈                  Take the maximum
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 78 bytes:

```
f=lambda x,c=0,j=1:j>len(x)or max([min(x[c:j])*(j-c),f(x,c,j+1),f(x,c+1,j+1)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBZboMwEP0upxjxg904Uc3SRkjOEXoBiipDjGrEYmGroqengwlRIlnWvGVm7Gf@3M84JGczLUsjOtlXVwkzq8UbawXP20unBjLTcYJezqToNaKiztuSvpL2WFPWEHSz9sBv5YF7UNJF92acHEjrAivCMCx4CccL8KCIGcS@ToMiwZoB3yH3MHmAGap4eybzTOqZdO@6k9kDyeO9eROe2HXDPnhb9e75xJ/7sO2N52fpdrz0gb8KGsxGgx6g0Z1TE/kcB8XAnqzptCPR1xBRmgcvklUgMERDMJATSmqS3bf6lR0DvZvXoWhHt7UKs2uIpCAEVIGZ9IAGp6yzYFb5GtHlHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>108</s></sup> 97 bytes

```c
m;s;j;k;f(a,n)int*a;{for(m=0;n--;)for(j=a[n];s=j;--j,m=s>m?s:m)for(k=n;k--;)s+=a[k]<j?k=0:j;j=m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZTdrqIwEMfvz1M0JCagkOVTxJ4eLzb7FMoFwXIOsNQTS7JmDa@@7NAWbJUAY@f378x0Wiy9z7Icxw5z3OAWV3bhMqdm/brA9@pytTviY@Z52JkGDSmOLMecNNjzGrcj/KM78H0nYEsYbicl34Cszd@bQ0v8fYMb0uFhhJioK2pmO@j@huCaHD3lfXDMEUH3YMCLK5Su0EWh5o2kNwKvi3R5rCIIEGkgWUACM@Ctse3CYsFiM2aq4@QF7/TIUqHjzKhoTq@XFviLJBL3kklfchC8qtQ94LmLayHlUilmubKL0kTSxNIk0mylSaXZSZO5qjRltRzCwWQKXv@ll8oWEueHGq3l0EUaDU0amjQyaWTS2KSxSROTJibdmnRr0tSkqUl3Jt2ZNDNpZtLAf2qH/8Sf2xU4Wofp7ZuWPT3rBy@eD8V0gEL5wNbBfqVqZnlhvEflV3Fdw5uWLb3KANbp9is83bKf8CSWi/RxZKnZ8N0ie0peszO9wTQfq5/vc@FzWY/SFw9Gm41QOyKY/KwfhxLCyYMpNDnWMWKKshf6qEnVA7UwkcpZNNP1fQVRZVsrvjrD@urDtMi9dQTTH@vcMfNxCAa7AH9upp@Cf@n8cylzihx5H2h1Rit@YhCeu0urOSF0TjW8DeO/svpdfPLR@/Mf)

Inputs a pointer to an array of positive integers and its length (because pointers in C carry no length info).
Returns the area of the largest rectangle in the skyline.

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 29 bytes

`M(ƒ(z(Ŀ(s(i))) *(m(∋) l(∋))))`

A port of [UnrelatedString's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242802/108218).

### Explanation

```
M(                Largest element of
  ƒ(              For
    z(Ŀ(s(i)))    every contiguous sublist of the input,
    *(m(∋) l(∋))  multiply its smallest item by its length
  )               and make a list of the results.
)
                  implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
▲m§*▼LQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0TbmHlms9mrbHJ/D////RhjrGOiY6RjqmQNo4FgA)

#### Explanation

```
▲m§*▼LQ
 m    Q   for each contiguous sublist
  §*      multiply it's
    ▼L    minimum value by it's length
▲         maximum of that
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
a=>Math.max(...a.map((n,i)=>(g=d=>a[i+=d]>=n&&g(d)+n)(-1,g(1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc9LDoIwEAbgvafoykwDlJSHuik38ASki4aXGCxEiPH2tRbUiJUwmUxm8WXyz1ncRJ9d627wZJsXqmRKsOQohhO5iDsQQoReOgDp1pglULGcJSKtHZbzhMnttoIcOxKDR90KKNalslb2bVOQpq2ghJRy9FMYI99HdDOjgYsCbqXRnIaauuj79h9KDQ1X0lhf1ZPPaGyhkaHRJ8YijS2UBvYEI19hn4@9MpsPR7uz0ND0O0vAR3pYolNPdK8e)

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242995/44718)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 13 bytes

```
xM(mn*×l)<cg
```

In the interested of transparency, since hgl is under heavy development some features used in this answer were only merged into master recently.

### Explanation

We just use the most straightforward possible algorithm.

`cg` gets all contiguous sublists we take these as the footprints for potential boxes.  We then for each of these multiply it's length by it's minimum element with `mn*×l` and take the maximum overall.

This is just a simpler version of the algorithm employed in [the more interesting version of this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242982/56656).

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 bytes

```hs
f l=maximum[x*(minimum$take x t)|t<-scanr(:)[]l,x<-[1..length t]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDLDoIwEEX3/YpZsAADJOWhxoA/QrpoFITQVgM1YeG/Y0FeYjGZNJ1zp525k9O6TBlr2wxYzGlT8CdPmp3JC9FdDUnLFBqQ1ktGTn2hojJPVkKY3UROgl2XpeImc5CEtJwWAmK43hHAoyqEBAMySDCBb@DZ4K2Zr5gNP6W4x74Gh6panRol6JVA/1vQv9wQw1HfmmNsqxvI72Nq4f0rGYJA223HOQNGw1bUPUDzNj7ptIUpndwrEqK16yUMFxB7aG1zpit/StgjvS8lHZHej5IObw)